# How to trim util the last row meet condition within groups in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Problem Description:
Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1,2,3,3,4,1,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
               "variable": ["A", "A", "A","A","A","A", "A", "A","A","A", "B", "B", "B","B","B","B" ,"C", "C", "C","C", "D","D","D","D","D","D"],
               "no": [1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5,1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,9],
               "value": [0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112,0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215,
                         0.119209, -1.044236, -0.861849, -0.234,0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215,
                         0.119209, -1.044236, -0.861849, 0.332,0.87]})
```

where the df would be

```
print(df)
    date variable   no     value
0      1        A  1.0  0.469112
1      1        A  1.0  0.469112
2      3        A  1.5 -1.135632
3      4        A  1.5  1.212112
4      3        A  1.5 -1.135632
5      4        A  1.5  1.212112
6      2        A  2.2 -0.282863
7      2        A  2.2 -0.282863
8      3        A  3.5 -1.509059
9      3        A  3.5 -1.509059
10     4        B  1.0  0.469112
11     1        B  1.1 -1.044236
12     1        B  1.2 -0.173215
13     1        B  1.3  0.119209
14     4        B  2.0 -0.861849
15     4        B  3.0 -0.234000
16     1        C  1.5 -1.135632
17     2        C  1.5  1.212112
18     1        C  2.2 -0.282863
19     1        C  3.5 -1.509059
20     3        D  1.1 -1.044236
21     2        D  1.2 -0.173215
22     3        D  1.3  0.119209
23     3        D  2.0 -0.861849
24     4        D  3.0  0.332000
25     4        D  9.0  0.870000
```

And then I wanna:

1. Sort based on columns `variable` and `no`,
2. Trim each group until the last row meets a condition, say, I would like to trim the group (by single column, say `variable`) until the last row where the value in column `value` is greater than 0, in other words, to drop rest of rows after the last row that meets the condition.

I have tried `groupby-apply`

```
df.groupby('variable', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.iloc[: x.where(x['value'] > 0).last_valid_index() + 1,  ]))
```

but the result is incorrect:

```
      date variable   no     value
0 0      1        A  1.0  0.469112
  1      1        A  1.0  0.469112
  2      3        A  1.5 -1.135632
  3      4        A  1.5  1.212112
  4      3        A  1.5 -1.135632
  5      4        A  1.5  1.212112
1 10     4        B  1.0  0.469112
  11     1        B  1.1 -1.044236
  12     1        B  1.2 -0.173215
  13     1        B  1.3  0.119209
  14     4        B  2.0 -0.861849
  15     4        B  3.0 -0.234000
2 16     1        C  1.5 -1.135632
  17     2        C  1.5  1.212112
  18     1        C  2.2 -0.282863
  19     1        C  3.5 -1.509059
3 20     3        D  1.1 -1.044236
  21     2        D  1.2 -0.173215
  22     3        D  1.3  0.119209
  23     3        D  2.0 -0.861849
  24     4        D  3.0  0.332000
  25     4        D  9.0  0.870000
```

as you may see the end of group B and C are not greater than 0.

Anyone who could provide a solution and explain why my solution does not work would be highly appreciated.

Plus. Since the size of dataframe is way larger than the example here, I assume we had better not reverse the dataframe.

Comment: In case the question is unclear, I wanna find the last row whose value is greater than 0 and remove the rest rows in the corresponding group

Comment: are groups defined by the 'variable' column only?

Comment: Yes, group by 'variable' column only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df = df.sort_values(['variable', 'no'])
(df.groupby('variable')
    .apply( 
         lambda x: x.iloc[:np.where(x.value.gt(0), range(len(x)), 0).max() + 1]
    ))
```

**Output**

```
             date variable   no     value
variable                                 
A        0      1        A  1.0  0.469112
         5      1        A  1.0  0.469112
         3      3        A  1.5 -1.135632
         4      4        A  1.5  1.212112
         8      3        A  1.5 -1.135632
         9      4        A  1.5  1.212112
B        15     4        B  1.0  0.469112
         12     1        B  1.1 -1.044236
         10     1        B  1.2 -0.173215
         11     1        B  1.3  0.119209
C        18     1        C  1.5 -1.135632
         19     2        C  1.5  1.212112
D        22     3        D  1.1 -1.044236
         20     2        D  1.2 -0.173215
         21     3        D  1.3  0.119209
         23     3        D  2.0 -0.861849
         24     4        D  3.0  0.332000
         25     4        D  9.0  0.870000
```

Comment: It works! Would you mind explain why using `last_valid_index()` fails?

Comment: `last_valid_index` returns the index of the last non-na value, in this case, you're working with boolean values, `True` and `False` are non-na values, so the method will always return the last element index

Comment: yes, but I try to use `where` to convert the `True` and `False` to `Nan` and real value. It is wired that it seems that group A is correct but the following sections are not.